# I need help to place a function so my code runs after the DOM has been rendered

Tags: javascript

I have a line of code that runs faster than the DOM so I need a timeout-function but I don't know where to put it.

```
function testing() {
  var newHeadline = document.createElement("h1");
  newHeadline.textContent = "Headline";

  document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm")[0].insertBefore(newHeadline, document.getElementsByClassName("text-content")[0]);
  for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0] != undefined) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].parentElement.remove();


      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use window.onload. window.onload ensures that first everything in the window including scripts and images have been loaded, and after everything is loaded it call the function which is supplied.

```js
window.onload=function testing() {


  var newHeadline = document.createElement("h1");
  newHeadline.textContent = "Headline";

  document.getElementsByClassName("col-sm")[0].insertBefore(newHeadline, document.getElementsByClassName("text-content")[0]);
  for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0] != undefined) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0].parentElement.remove();


      return true

    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DOMContentLoaded` event if you want to wait until all HTML has been loaded and JavaScript has been parsed, or the `load` event if you also want to wait until all the images and styles have been applied.

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") testing();
else addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", testing);
```

OR

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") testing();
else addEventListener("load", testing);
```

You can also use an empty `timeout`, to run the function right after the script has been parsed and run.

```
setTimeout(testing, 0);
```